# Find and remove unique_ptr from a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, unique-ptr

I have a `map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Cls>> my_map`. I would like to move out some value from this map, to have the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<Cls> cls = my_map.get_and_erase("some str");
```

`erase` doesn't return a value unfortunately. What is my best approach here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm:

- Use `find` to get an iterator to the element.
- Move from the element.
- Erase using the iterator.

Answer (score 6):

Since C++17 you have [`std::map::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract):

```
// if the key exists in the map, it'll be deleted after this:
auto cls_node =  my_map.extract("some str");

if(not cls_node.empty()) // cls_node.mapped() gives access to the mapped value
```

Comment: This is nice! Does this work with the unique_ptr, i.e. it will move it out?

Comment: @gruszczy Yes, it's in the node you get, so `auto cls = std::move(cls_node.value());` will give it to you. As a bonus, if you aim to re-insert the node with a different key, you can just change the key: `cls_node.key() = "new value"; my_map.insert(std::move(cls_node));`  which should be a quicker key-change than the old way (in theory - I've never measured it).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upvoted this, but I will accept the other answer for now, since it's earlier C++ versions friendly. One day this should become the accepted answer though.

Comment: @yfede Thanks! I've corrected it!